# How to configure NiFi PutS3Object processor to use flow attributes for S3 credentials

Tags: apache-nifi

I assume that the PutS3Object processor can resolve a reference to the Access Key and Secret Key as these two configuration parameters support expression language. But I am unable to get it to work.

I have successfully put files into an S3 bucket by configuring the PutS3Object processor with the Access Key and Secret Key with the actual values. But, when I try to set those values in an UpdateAttribute processor and then use an expression to reference the attributes in the Access Key and Secret Key settings they do not appear to be set and the put object call fails.

Following is the error message when Access Key and Secret Key are defined as ${s3.accessKey} and ${s3.secretAccessKey} respectively. Those two attributes have been set in an UpdateAttribute processor prior to the PutS3Object processor.

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The authorization header is malformed; a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must be provided in the credential. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed;

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The authorization header is malformed; a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must be provided in the credential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the expressions allowed for AWS access key properties do not include FlowFile attributes.  The expressions are intended to be used with globally configured "Variable Registry" values, so that access keys can provided as part of the server deployment.  The feature is described under [Custom Properties](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#custom_properties) in the NiFi System Administrator's Guide.

Allowing FlowFile attributes would require a feature request via the [NiFi JIRA ticket system](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI).